# Different custom header image on different page

Tags: headers, custom-header, header-image

I am now creating a website for my client, this client wants me to make each page of the section of header image able to be easily uploaded by them in wordpress admin panel.

This is the code I have in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
$args = array(
    'width'         => 950,
    'height'        => 150,
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
    'uploads'       => true,
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

This code is for a single banner image. What if I want to make it available for different and other pages?

Comment: Hey! Are you able to use the featured image as the header?

Comment: why not using featured image as the header?

Answer (score 3):

create new file in your theme with name header-custom.php
next copy this code into that file

```
    class customheaderMetabox {
    private $screen = array(
        'post',
        'page',
    );
    private $meta_fields = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Add Image Header',
            'id' => 'addimageheader_24744',
            'type' => 'media',
        ),
    );
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'media_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_fields' ) );
    }
    public function add_meta_boxes() {
        foreach ( $this->screen as $single_screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'customheader',
                __( 'Custom Header', 'textdomain' ),
                array( $this, 'meta_box_callback' ),
                $single_screen,
                'advanced',
                'default'
            );
        }
    }
    public function meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'customheader_data', 'customheader_nonce' );
        echo 'Allow you to add custom header in every page';
        $this->field_generator( $post );
    }
    public function media_fields() {
        ?><script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                if ( typeof wp.media !== 'undefined' ) {
                    var _custom_media = true,
                    _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
                    $('.customheader-media').click(function(e) {
                        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
                        var button = $(this);
                        var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
                        _custom_media = true;
                            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
                            if ( _custom_media ) {
                                $('input#'+id).val(attachment.url);
                            } else {
                                return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
                            };
                        }
                        wp.media.editor.open(button);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.add_media').on('click', function(){
                        _custom_media = false;
                    });
                }
            });
        </script><?php
    }
    public function field_generator( $post ) {
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
            $label = '<label for="' . $meta_field['id'] . '">' . $meta_field['label'] . '</label>';
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_field['id'], true );
            if ( empty( $meta_value ) ) {
                $meta_value = $meta_field['default']; }
            switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                case 'media':
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input style="width: 80%%" id="%s" name="%s" type="text" value="%s"> <input style="width: 19%%" class="button customheader-media" id="%s_button" name="%s_button" type="button" value="Upload" />',
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_value,
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id']
                    );
                    break;
                default:
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input %s id="%s" name="%s" type="%s" value="%s">',
                        $meta_field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'style="width: 100%"' : '',
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['type'],
                        $meta_value
                    );
            }
            $output .= $this->format_rows( $label, $input );
        }
        echo '<table class="form-table"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';
    }
    public function format_rows( $label, $input ) {
        return '<tr><th>'.$label.'</th><td>'.$input.'</td></tr>';
    }
    public function save_fields( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['customheader_nonce'] ) )
            return $post_id;
        $nonce = $_POST['customheader_nonce'];
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'customheader_data' ) )
            return $post_id;
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;
        foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] ) ) {
                switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                    case 'email':
                        $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                }
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
            } else if ( $meta_field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], '0' );
            }
        }
    }
}
if (class_exists('customheaderMetabox')) {
    new customheaderMetabox;
};
```

next include file in function.php
using this code `include(get_template_directory().'/header-custom.php');`

after this step you will see new metabox in post and page on wp admin.

next if you want to show that image put this code in your header.php or in page.php  `<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'addimageheader_24744' , true);?>">`

Comment: This works. Don't forget to start the block with `<?php`

Also on line 69 you can get rid of the undefined array error with ?? null `$meta_value = $meta_field['default']  ?? null; }`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solution

I created a custom field called banner and placed it in  header.php file or header-single.php file.

```
<?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'banner', true)) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'banner', true); ?>" />
<?php else : ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think it work fine

Comment: How shall i use this code? I'm not really good in php coding. Thanks!

Comment: hey plz check this url it is very simple to create meta box and get image  http://www.chandankumar.in/add-additional-featured-image-field-in-wordpress/